# Reactive Extensions error handling with Observable SelectMany

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I'm trying to write file watcher on certain folder using the reactive extensions library
The idea is to monitor hard drive folder for new files, wait until file is written completely and push event to the subscriber. I do not want to use `FileSystemWatcher` since it raises Changed event twice for the same file.

So I've wrote it in the "reactive way" (I hope) like below:

```cs
var provider = new MessageProviderFake();
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), NewThreadScheduler.Default).SelectMany(_ => provider.GetFiles());
using (source.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine(_.Name), () => Console.WriteLine("completed to Console")))
{
    Console.WriteLine("press Enter to stop");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

However I can't find "reactive way" to handle errors. For example, the file directory can be located on the external drive and became unavailable because of connection problem.
So I've added `GetFilesSafe` that will handle exception errors from the Reactive Extensions:

```cs
static IEnumerable<MessageArg> GetFilesSafe(IMessageProvider provider)
{
    try
    {
        return provider.GetFiles();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return new MessageArg[0];
    }
}
```

and used it like

```cs
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), NewThreadScheduler.Default).SelectMany(_ => GetFilesSafe(provider));
```

Is there better way to make `SelectMany` to call `provider.GetFiles()` even when an exception has been raised? I'm using error counter in such cases to repeat the reading operation N times and then fail (terminate the process).

Is there "try N time and wait Q seconds between attempts" in the Reactive Extensions?

There is a problem with `GetFilesSafe` also: it returns `IEnumerable<MessageArg>` for lazy reading however it can raise on iteration and exception will be thrown somewhere in the `SelectMany`

Comment: What does the `GetFiles` do? Enumerates all the files of the folder?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes, it returns list of objects with file name in the Name property.

Comment: That sounds quite inefficient, especially if the folder contains a large number of files. I would prefer to use a `FileSystemWatcher`, after fixing its shortcomings.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias actually the idea is to scan for new files, process them and move to archive. It is not supposed to scan the same huge set of files again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [`Retry`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html#collapseRxNET) extension, that just subscribes to the observable again if the current one errors, but it sounds like that won't offer the flexibility you want.

You could build something using [`Catch`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html), which subscribes to the observable you give it if an error occurs on the outer one. Something like the following (untested):

```cs
IObservable<Thing> GetFilesObs(int times, bool delay) {
    return Observable
        .Return(0)
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delay ? <delay_time> : 0))
        .SelectMany(_ => Observable.Defer(() => GetFilesErroringObservable()))
        .Catch(Observable.Defer(() => GetFilesObs(times - 1, true)));
}

// call with:
GetFilesObs(<number_of_tries>, false);
```

As written, this doesn't do anything with the errors other than trigger a retry. In particular, when enough errors have happened, it will just complete without an error, which might not be what you want.